# threejs как вычислить центр модели, выравнивание моделей

Tags: javascript, three.js

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал изучать threejs и на основе уже готового редактора попробовал написать функцию которая выделенную модель ставит в центр над сценой и возникла проблема:

- если модель повёрнута определённым образом так что бы изменилась её высота то правильно расположить ее не получается, она оказывается то выше чем надо то наоборот ниже в зависимости от углов поворота, которые приводят к смещению центра.

вот код функции которая ставит модель в центр

```
    editor.selected.geometry.center();
    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(editor.selected);    
    var newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, box.size().y/2, 0);    
    editor.execute(new SetPositionCommand(editor.selected, newPosition));

    console.log('box.size.y = ' + box.size().y);
```

ссылка на код в работе http://lexsandbox.netne.net/editor/ (вкладка Alignment-AlignCenter)

скрин как должно быть http://joxi.ru/5mdo7aoinGy5r1 - углы поворотов = 0, всё отлично

и скрин проблемы - http://joxi.ru/EA41k31HqVQ0rb - в текущем состоянии box.size.y = 105.89974660644481, position.y = 52.95, и это было бы правильно если бы центр не был смещён

Как в этом случае правильно вычислить центр и правильно расположить модель над сценой?

Для работы используется threejs editor r79, ни одна строка кода кроме отвечающего за пункт меню и выравнивание не менялась